# retrieve posted blog content in wordpress based on id or permalink

Tags: blogs

I hope somebody know the answer of my question.

How do I retrieve posted blog content in wordpress based on **id** or **permalink**? I need the API.

Thank you

Comment: what language? more info please

Comment: @Shoban WordPress is a PHP platform, I guess it would need to use PHP.

Comment: in C# language... So, you mean that it is not possible to retrieved posted blog content in another language?
Thanks

Comment: If you need to interface with it via .Net, why not use a .Net based blog such as BlogEngine .Net?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress documentation is your friend: [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

e.g:

```
<?php
$my_id = 7;
$post = get_post($my_id); 
$content = $post->post_content;
?>
```

Comment: hmm... actually i need to do it in C# (ASP.net) :-(

Comment: e.g i have post my blog in wordpress and i want it to be showed in my website. Also i need it programmatically in C#. Any idea such as open-standard API, like RSS or Javascript API?